# Gradle migrate publishing from gradle 4.x to 5.x?

Tags: gradle, publishing

How to migrate the following publishing from gradle 4 to 5?

```
publishing {
    publications {
        foo(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId "foo"
            artifact jar

            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

                def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', 'mygroup')
                dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', 'bar')
                dependencyNode.appendNode('version', '1.0')

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works for gradle 4.5.1. But for gradle 5.4.1, error:

```
Execution failed for task ':publishFooPublicationToMavenLocal'.
> Failed to publish publication 'foo' to repository 'mavenLocal'
   > Invalid publication 'foo': artifactId is not a valid Maven identifier ([A-Za-z0-9_\-.]+).
```

Answer (score 0):

With gradle 4.8+ you have to enclose the `publishing{}` block inside a `project.afterEvaluate`

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
      publications {
        foo(MavenPublication) {
          artifactId "foo"
          artifact jar

          pom.withXml {
            def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

            def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
            dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', 'mygroup')
            dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', 'bar')
            dependencyNode.appendNode('version', '1.0')

         }
      }

    }
}
```

You can find the [official doc here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html#rel4.8:deferred_configuration):

> Prior to Gradle 4.8, the publishing {} block was implicitly treated as if all the logic inside it was executed after the project was evaluated. This was confusing, because it was the only block that behaved that way. As part of the stabilization effort in Gradle 4.8, we are deprecating this behavior and asking all users to migrate their build.